# Java: VTD-XML 2.10: How to select all element in depth 1

Tags: java, xpath, depth, vtd-xml

I am using VTD-XML 2.10 in Java.

I have problem on how to select all elements which has depth of 1.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use xpath /*

Comment: I used Nav.toElement(Nav Direction Constants). Then now, I change it to xpath /* it run faster than before. Thanks a lot and also many by answering my inquiries at vtd-xml mailing list.